# Opening XPages from launch settings break my stylesheet references

Tags: css, redirect, styles, xpages, relative-path

I have noticed that sometimes relative links from i.e urls in stylesheets are not working if the path in the address bar is pointing to the nsf instead of the xsp

so if I have the following inline style in a panel

```
background-image:url('footer-bg.png')
```

and I access my site using **acme.com/mypage.nsf**  (with a launch propery set to start.xsp)
the background is not loading

but if I use the fullpath to the xsp the background is working fine e.g **acme.com/mypage.nsf/start.xsp**

How can I solve this issue so that my inline stylesheet background always work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to always add a trailing slash if you autolaunch an XPage in the database properties.

```
var h=window.location.href;
if(h.indexOf(".xsp")==-1){
  if(h.substring(h.length,h.length-1)!="/"){
     window.location.href+="/"
}}
```

I have written a blog post about it here
http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2013/quicktip-get-right-path-when-autolaunching-an-xpage

or use this jQuery code that Thomas added

```
 $(function(){
 var h=window.location.href;
if(h.indexOf(".xsp")==-1){
if(h.substring(h.length,h.length-1,1)!="/"){
 window.location.href+="/"
}}
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I have a snippet for that that resides in my layout CC that I use on every page: http://snippets.notesx.net/Privat/osnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?documentId=13EBFA7FDDC4354EC1257C120005018E

In the beforePageLoad you put the following code:

```
var url = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURI();
if(url.indexOf(".xsp")==-1){
    if(url.endsWith("/")){
        url = url.substr(0, url.length-1)
    }
    context.redirectToPage(url+view.getPageName())
}
```